# Ag-Grid: How to save and reload column after applying filter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, filter, ag-grid

Using Ag-Grid, we can apply filter columns. I need to allow the user to save the column filter order(in sql backend). 
I use this method, but it allows to save the column order..

```js
onGridReady: function(params){
  var columnState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myColumnState'));
  var filterState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myfilterState'));

  if (columnState) {
    params.columnApi.setColumnState(columnState);
  }
  if (filterState) {
    params.columnApi.setsetFilterModel(filterState);
  }
},

onColumnMoved: function(params){
  var columnState = JSON.stringify(params.columnApi.getColumnState());
  var filterState = JSON.stringify(params.columnApi.getFilterModel());
  localStorage.setItem('myColumnState', columnState);
  localStorage.setItem('myfilterState', filterState);
},
```

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by column filter order?

Comment: I did filtering in some columns...while refreshing filtered columns should not change...Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your example, `getFilterModel()` is not a part of columnApi, instead you should do something like below

while saving state in `onColumnMoved`:

```
  var filterState = JSON.stringify(params.api.getFilterModel()); // it is in gridApi
  localStorage.setItem('myfilterState', filterState);
```

reading back from saved state in `onGridReady`:

```
params.api.setFilterModel(filterState);
```

You can follow this [example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-definitions/#column-api-example) from the docs.

Comment: it works...If I hide any columns using the side bar toolpanel is it possible to do the same? It only works if I move any columns...Is there any other event like 'oncolumnmoved'?

Comment: Yes. You can try inmplementing this event onDisplayedColumnsChanged